# undefined method `close!' for nil:NilClass

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm getting a really weird error with rails. It happens periodically every so often (and it *seems* to be when I wake up my computer after a long while)

```
undefined method `close!' for nil:NilClass
 (in /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/turbolinks-1.3.0/lib/assets/javascripts/turbolinks.js.coffee)
```

Eventually it will fix itself. It doesn't fix if I restart the server and it happens with different coffeescript files constantly. In the case above, it is turbolinks. However before I restarted the server and refreshed a few times it was `history.js.coffee` - What is going on here?

EDIT: Now after restarting it works magically. Obviously it's not a problem now but it's happening at random points and it is slowing down my workflow. It sounds like a permissions problem but they all seem correct.q

Comment: Have you got any other code? Such as when `close!` is being called?

Comment: That's the thing: There is no code. There's no reference to `close!` in the codebase at all. This is some kind of rails method that's failing. It's nothing to do with my code and it fixes itself after a few restarts

Comment: Hmmm  - is this a problem in production or development? If it's production (and you're using something like Heroku), it could be the case your dyno is winding down

Comment: Development at current but I haven't tested in production yet

Comment: Just as an update: It's happening again now. However, the referenced JS file here is something that I changed about 5-10 minutes ago and `scp`d to the staging server so I think it may have to do with a lock being placed on that file

Comment: @andy : You solved this issue? , I am facing same , any clue will be helpful.

Comment: @Senthil Sadly not. It seemed to go away on it's own. Very very strange

Comment: @andy : Actually I fixed it by removing the JS file which loaded twice, but don't know how to relate it with this bug.

Answer (score 0):

This is most likely because the CoffeeScript cannot be compiled on the fly.

In production check things like enough disk space and enough available memory.