# undefined method `close!' for nil:NilClass

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am new to rails.
I followed the tutorial in this page and tried to generate a hello world page:

http://arubystory.blogspot.com/2013/11/tutorial-saying-hello-world-with-ruby.html

however, after I finished all the steps all the steps and started the server, I got the following errors: can anyone help? Thank you in advance!

```
Showing /home/ec2-user/testApp4/app/views/layouts/application.html.erb where line #6    raised:

undefined method `close!' for nil:NilClass
  (in /home/ec2-user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/turbolinks-2.2.2/lib/assets/javascripts/turbolinks.js.coffee)
Extracted source (around line #6):

  <head>
<title>TestApp4</title>
<%= stylesheet_link_tag    'application', media: 'all', 'data-turbolinks-track' => true %>
<%= javascript_include_tag 'application', 'data-turbolinks-track' => true %>
<%= csrf_meta_tags %>
  </head>
  <body>
```

Comment: it means the object that you are calling the method `close` is `nil`. post your code by editing your answer

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21523237/undefined-method-close-for-nilnilclass

Comment: @WaliAli but I am not sure which codes to post...sry I am really new to rails

Comment: @SebastianWramba yes, I have read that post. It is fixed "magically".... but I can not fixed using the same way..so I posted it again.

Comment: Never mind about posting more code. I checked out the tutorial link and replicated the code. I'm not getting the error you are getting. it works fine for me. I don't see anywhere a method called `close` in the tutorial. I have no idea why you getting it.

Comment: This is an odd problem. To work around it, try editing your `Gemfile` and commenting out the "tubolinks" gem. The `bundle install` again and restart your server. That will probably get you past the error. But it may pop up somewhere else depending on if your problem is with turbolinks, coffeescript, or something else. You might also try `gem uninstall turbolinks; gem uninstall coffee-script` and then `bundle install` again. Sadly, although you are a beginner, you have hit a weird problem.

Comment: It may mean you don't have JQuery called on your page?

Comment: @WaliAli Thank you so much. I made a new rails application and follow the tutorial again. There is no error this time.

Comment: @gwcoffey Thank you for your work-around. I made a new rails application and follow the tutorial again. There is no error this time. the problem is solved "magically"..Thank you again for you advise.

Comment: @RichPeck It seems the problem is not about Jquery..